# Confusing rails div id naming

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have started using jQuery and rails. I have made a simple form that submits to the database and updates the page without reloading with ajax.

In my jQuery functions I used $"#new_comment" for the id name (in my application.js and create.js.erb files) but on my places/show view file, I named the div "add_comment" and it works..

I renamed it new_comment and it breaks! Can someone explain it please? I get an error: "no action responded to 1"

My function in my controller is "create".

```
#views/places/show.html.erb
<div id="new_comment" style="display:none">
 #form goes here
</div>

#application.js
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function(){
    $("#new_comment").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
    })
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("new_comment").submitWithAjax();
})

#create.js.erb
$("#new_comment").before('<div id="flash_notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');

$("#comments_count").html("<%= pluralize(@comment.place.comments.count, 'suggestion') %>");

$("#comments").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment)) %>");

$("#new_comment")[0].reset();

#comments_controller.rb
    def create
      @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
      @comment = @place.comments.create!(params[:comment])

    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for your suggestion. Remember to share with friends!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to place_comments_path(@place)}
      format.js
      end
end
```

Comment: You're attaching the `submit` event to the container div, not the form within.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. It was applying the id automatically anyway but I guess it's better to be explicit and know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to attaching the `submit` event to the wrong element, you are restricting your jquery plugin to just `#new_comment`. You should abstract it some and use the element that you're passing in when you call `submitWithAjax`. You can add an id to the form or change the selector in your document.ready function to target the child form.

```
#application.js
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function(myForm){
    $(myForm).submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
    })
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new_comment_form").submitWithAjax();
})
```

You'll also need to correct the `reset` call in your create.js. The other javascript appears to do what you expect.

Comment: That doesn't work but if I use this.submit(function) and use no parameter it works. Thanks.